# using multi route for one component in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-routing

i create a component `Dashboard` for admin . i pass the username in route for find user info .

this is my routing :

```
{path:'dashboard/:username',component:DashboardComponent,children:[
{path:'role',component:RoleComponent},
```

and i using this url :

```
localhost:4200/panel/dashboard/kia@kia.com
```

in my `Dashborad` Compoent have a menu for users .

when i need to go `Role` component i need to use this url :

`localhost:4200/panel/dashboard/role`

but it not go in the `Role` Component but when i using this :

`{path:'dashboard',component:DashboardComponent,children:[`

it works .

how can i multi route for `Dashboard` component ?

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below in the Route:

```
{
   path:'dashboard/:username', component: DashboardComponent
},
{
   path:'dashboard/:username/role',component: RoleComponent
}
```

Comment: its not work . still have thar problem . i use this:`{path:'dashboard',component:DashboardComponent,children:[
        {path:':username',component:DashboardComponent},
        {path:'role',component:RoleComponent},`

Comment: Can you explain what you required in brief?

Comment: Try to use `*` in childrens array

Comment: when i Enter the `Dashboard` i use this url:`localhost:4200/panel/dashboard/kia@kia.com` and when i need to go `RoleComponent` i need to user this url:`localhost:4200/panel/dashboard/kia@kia.com/role` but when i click the link , it go to this url :`localhost:4200/panel/dashboard/role` and it not work , now my question is , `How Can i go to RoleComponent?`

Comment: @Kianoush check updated answer! Have tested in my local environment

Comment: i using your code in `Approuting` and this in Url : `<label routerLink='/panel/dashboard/{{userInfo.userName}}/role'>مدیریت نقش ها</label>` but still not work . still it go this url : `localhost:4200/panel/dashboard/role`

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185409/discussion-between-kianoush-and-prashant-pimpale).

Answer (score 1):

For the route definition you have, your path should look like:

```
localhost:4200/panel/dashboard/{user}/role
```

For example:

```
localhost:4200/panel/dashboard/kia@kia.com/role
```

If you are looking into adding Role as a menu on the account html, you'd have to do something like this:

```
[routerLink]="['/dashboard', user , '/role']
```

Use that in any elements, like in a link like:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard', user, '/role/]"> Role </a>
```

`user` is the variable that holds user identifier, example `kia@kia.com`

Comment: Access this route where? In the component or html?

Comment: access in `AdminRoutingModule`?

Comment: and i dont need to show username in this url : `localhost:4200/panel/dashboard/kia@kia.com/role`